# Why is Python reference equality not working?

Tags: python

I have a class with an array called `self.sheets`. I have a function, `find_sheet` which will do a comparison on the titles if a string is passed, or do a reference comparison if a `Worksheet` is passed. Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
class Worksheet:
    pass


class Spread:
    @property
    def sheets(self):
        return [Worksheet() for i in range(5)]

    def find_sheet(self, sheet):
        for ix, obj in enumerate(self.sheets):
            print("comparing {} is {}".format(id(obj), id(sheet)))
            if obj is sheet:
                print("found you")


s = Spread()
s.find_sheet(s.sheets[0])
```

This outputs `comparing 140134415396760 is 140134393512344`

Comment: yeah, it looks like you have two different objects there. we can only speculate as to why you expected them to be the same object. generally, using `is` here would not be the way to go. in other words, it looks like `is` is working just fine, why do you expect it to behave differently?

Comment: how are they different objects? I'm passing in `obj.sheets[0]`, then in `pdb` I'm stopping at the first iteration of `enumerate(self.sheets)`, which should be the same as `self.sheets[0]` (and in this case, `self` = `obj`)

Comment: we can only speculate unless you provide a [mcve] . it seems pretty clear, *they are all different objects*

Comment: As a side note, `isinstance(sheet, Worksheet)` probably is not necessary. `if sheet is worksheet:` should suffice.

Comment: Works for me. It prints `found you`

Comment: If it works as expected, then it's not a reproducible example, and we still can't help you.  Try again.

Comment: You guys are right, I found my problem... leaving question and answer here in case it helps anyone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. When I refer to `s.sheets`, it's calling the property function and generating a new list each time. So when I pass `s.sheets[0]`, it's actually a different object than the first object when iterating through `self.sheets`.

Lesson here is... be careful when using properties, they behave differently than variables.

Comment: Better still, beware premature optimization, and don't reach for reference equality as a computational shortcut unless you have a clear need.

Comment: True, in this case the issue is that `Worksheet` is implemented elsewhere and it doesn't have `__eq__` implemented. I ended up comparing the `id` property on the object, which works for this usecase.